# Bash statement works differently while executed from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, groovy, pipeline

I'm dealing with below command that works perfectly fine directly in target machine (it returns files older than 14 days in `SomePath` excluding `SomeFolder`):

```
find SomePath -mtime +14 -not -path "SomePath/SomeFolder/*" -not -path "SomePath/SomeFolder/" -print
```

When I try to run it on some Jenkins node (`SomeNodeName`) inside pipeline, filtering does not work though (it returns also files from `SomeFolder`). Stage code:

```
steps {
script {
    groovy_script = '''#!/bin/bash
        println "find SomePath -mtime +14 -not -path \\"SomePath/SomeFolder/*\\" -not -path \\"SomePath/SomeFolder\\" -print".execute().text
        '''.trim()

        Jenkins.instance.slaves.find { agent ->
        agent.name == SomeNodeName
        }.with { agent ->
        nodeOutput = RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(groovy_script, agent.getChannel())
        }
        println nodeOutput
    }
}
```

Why results are not being filtered while executing inside pipeline and how should it be done?

Comment: The double backslashes look suspicious but I don't know how exactly the Groovy wrapper passes this to Bash. Off the cuff, I would switch to triple quotes around the script (those are supported in Groovy, right?) and take out the backslashes, or perhaps try with a single backslash instead of two. You could also try with single quotes instead of the backslashed double quotes.

Comment: @tripleee I tried changing ```\\"``` to ```'``` - works exactly the same. With single backslash and without backslashes at all there's an error.

Comment: "there's an error".  Is there an error message?

Comment: The "execute().text" seems to be misplaced.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Script1.groovy: 2: expecting '*', found '<EOF>' @ line 2, column 237.
SomeFolder" -print".execute().text
Where should be "execute().text" then? Without it commants are just printed and not executed

Comment: If this is executed as Groovy, then `"string".execute()` is a bad idea. Use the array version instead and get rid of all the "shell-isms"

Comment: All other observations aside: there's a difference between the two finds. In groovy the second `-not` path is missing a trailing slash.

Comment: In the future, please include error messages in the body of your question, not as a reply in a comment. Readerrs should have all the information they need just by reading your question, and not have to navigate an ever increasing string of comments/replys (-;! Good luck.

Comment: @cfrick could you please specify what you mean by "array version"?

Comment: what dies it mean `does not work though`?  if there is missing output - please explain it, if there is an error - show it.

Comment: @daggett it's described in the description - "it returns also files from SomeFolder"

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use list on which you do "execute" as somebody mentioned.
Also, you should explicitly call shell, either powershell or bash or whatever to explicitly show where execution takes place.
As far as command is concerned: you are using groovy script so you should just put groovy stuff and get rid of unneeded linux shell stuff as other stackoverflower mentioned. Also, you should avoid as much apostrophes (single and double quotes) as you can to make it clear when reading - luckily this is Groovy so you can use dollar slashy string here ([dollar slashy info link](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-strings#dollar-slashy-string)).

The result could look like this:

```
groovy_script = $/["sh", "-c", "find SomePath -mtime +14 -not -path SomePath/SomeFolder/*"].execute().text/$
```

On the top of it, I wouldn't create such a complex and error prone structure like you do here, but would think of some simpler solution of your problem.